# Can't Naviagate to Desired Page in Epub on clicking Table Of Contents

Tags: html, epub

I am creating an ePub file which includes the Table Of Contents created manually.
In the Table Of Contents HTML Page, I have given the link for the pages as

```
<a href ="../Text/html2.xhtml#SecondBookmark">Chapter 2</a>
```

But after creating the ePub file, I can't able to navigate to the page.
It is redirecting to a page 
https://calibre-internal.invalid/Text/html2.xhtml.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I assume you're talking about the toc .ncx file. Try to remove `../` before `Text/html2.xhtml#SecondBookmark` and also check the docs because I've never seen a toc structure like the one you used: https://github.com/krisztianmukli/epub-boilerplate/blob/master/samples/sample-book-with-multilevel-toc/OEBPS/toc.ncx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for not navigating to the page is the folder path. Instead of specifying the complete folder path, it is enough that we give only the file name in the href attribute.
For example,

```
<a href ="html2.xhtml#SecondBookmark">Chapter 2</a>
```